# PHP exec() hangs when starting javaw.exe

Tags: java, php, solr, exec, javaw

I have a php script that I want to use to start my solr jetty server. Something like this:

```
chdir("C:/solr-4.4.0/solr-4.4.0/example/");
echo getcwd();
exec("javaw -jar start.jar > output.log 2>&1 &");
echo 'done';
```

The problem is that if `javaw.exe` is not already running, the php script hangs and waits for it to finish. I thought that redirecting the output and adding the `&` to the end would take care of this but it doesn't....

**QUESTION:**

Is there way to start this process (javaw.exe), let it run in the background and continue executing the rest of my php script?

(WINDOWS 7 PRO 64 BIT)

Comment: your using linux syntax on a windows server

Comment: @Dagon what exactly is the problem with my syntax? the command executes, starts javaw.exe, and redirects the output to the log....i just dont want php waiting for a response, just start it and move on...

Answer (score 0):

for windows:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("javaw -jar start.jar > output.log", 0, false);
```

Comment: i changed the CurrentDirectory, still no success